# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'b64encode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I got an error by trying to do a simple base64 encoder. My file isn´t called bas64.py or anything related.

```
     datatoencode = input("Enter the data you want to encode: ")
     datatoencode_bytes = datatoencode.encode('ascii')
     encodedBytes = base64.b64encode(datatoencode_bytes)
     base64_datatoencode = encodedBytes.decode('ascii')
     print("Encoded data: " + base64_datatoencode)
```

Comment: Sorry but obviusly i imported base64

Comment: so this question is closed?

Comment: yes it is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you define a function called `base64` in your module somewhere? You can either rename the function, or import the `base64` module under an alias, like this: `import base64 as b64`. If you do the latter, don't forget to replace `base64.b64encode` by `b64.b64encode`.

Comment: Thank you so much I just realized that my func was called "encodetobase64"

Comment: Is your problem solved? You can click the check mark next to my answer to mark it as accepted. If my answer wasn't completely the right story, you can add your own answer to explain what exactly you did to solve the problem and accept your own answer. That way people having similar problems in the future can see what they need to do if they find this page on Google!